# ExtJS 4: How to associate model with another, pre-existing model by ID?

Tags: extjs, extjs4

Say I have have an instance of ModelA, which can 'hasMany' ModelB instances. Given the id for a ModelB record that already exists on the server, how do I associate model A with model B? (The API docs only show how to do this by simultaneously creating a new model B instance and database record.)

As an example, say I have an app that can be used schedule meetings with Person and Meeting objects. The server might return JSON like this for a meeting:

Meeting:

```
{
    id: '10',
    purpose: 'Code review',
    time: <timestamp>,
    attendees: [ 501, 532 ]
}
```

Person:

```
{ id: 501, name: 'Kermit', email: 'kermit@thefrog.com' }
```

The models might be defined like this:

```
Ext.define('Person', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
    fields: ['id', 'name', 'email'],
    proxy: {
        type: 'rest',
        url : 'data/people',
        reader: { type: 'json' }
    }
});

Ext.define('Meeting', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
    fields: ['id', 'purpose', 'time'],
    hasMany: { model: 'Person', name: 'attendees' }
    proxy: {
        type: 'rest',
        url : 'data/meetings',
        reader: { type: 'json' }
    }
});
```

I understand that once a meeting is loaded. I can call meeting.attendees() to access each Person model. But, given new attendee ID (e.g., 599), how do I add another person to the meeting? Is the only option to load the Person instance for id 599 and then add the that instance to 'attendees', like this?

```
Meeting.load(10, {
    success: function(meeting) {

        Person.load(599, {
            success: function(person) {
                meeting.attendees().add(person);
                meeting.save();
            }
        });

    }
})
```

When meeting.save() runs, would the POST correctly include just the ID of the person, like this?

```
{
    id: '10',
    purpose: 'Code review',
    time: <timestamp>,
    attendees: [ 501, 532, 599 ] <-- '599' is new attendee
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: You should probably be using a many to many relationship for this as a person can attend many meetings and meetings can have many persons. Lists,arrays, etc of ids is a bad thing.

Comment: Thanks for the input. That said, this was just a simplistic analogy. In reality, the association is truly a one-to-many and the preferred approach with the database (MongoDB) is t use an array of IDs. But point taken.

Comment: Here's an article about some work that was done to make EXT JS 4 better handle document databases. http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?127547-Sencha-Platform-denormalized-Data-patch I use the patched version of Sencha Touch with CouchDB.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To be honest... associations are best used for reading. Editing associated models aren't the best as there is no way to configure a writer or anything. For the UI, yes, add a new model to the store you get from attendees() but you need to also send that back to the server.

Comment: So when a meeting is saved, nothing for attendees() will be sent back?

Comment: Correct, unless you add a field called attendees to your Meeting model and handle updating the array manually. ExtJS doesn't handle denormalized data very well, it expects typical normalized database structure.